# React CSRF token issue on first render

Tags: reactjs, axios, csrf-token

I need help with csrf token issue.
Now on first render I am sending get request for CSRF token and then setting it as default header as below.

```
const { data } = await publicAxios.get('/csrf-token');
publicAxios.defaults.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = data.csrfToken;
authAxios.defaults.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = data.csrfToken;
```

Issue is on first render I am sending another POST requests also but that all requests fails with 403 code because that requests don't have 'X-CSRF-Token' header.
What can I do to solve this?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const FetchContext = createContext();
const { Provider } = FetchContext;

const FetchProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const publicAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: '/api' })
    const authAxios = axios.create({ baseURL: '/api' })
    authAxios.interceptors.response.use(
        response => {
            return response
        },
        error => {
            return Promise.reject(error)
        }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCsrfToken = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await publicAxios.get('/csrf-token');
                publicAxios.defaults.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = data.csrfToken;
                authAxios.defaults.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = data.csrfToken;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        };
        getCsrfToken();
    }, [authAxios, publicAxios]);

    return (
        <Provider value={{ authAxios, publicAxios }}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    );
};

export { FetchContext, FetchProvider }
```

This is how I am using it

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FetchContext } from "../Context/index";


const UsersList = ({ children }) => {
    const { authAxios } = useContext(FetchContext);
    const [userList, setUserList] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getUsers() {
            try {
                const { data } = await authAxios.post(
                    '/users/list'
                );
                if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
                    setUserList(data)
                } else {
                    setUserList('No');
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
                setUserList('Error')
            }
        }

        getUsers()
    }, [authAxios]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            hello
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: are you sending that post request before the get request, in parallel or strictly after?

Comment: @apokryfos I am sending in parallel. that all other requests are initiated from different components using authAxios exported from above code through Provider. so I can't understand how to send this all requests after getting csrf token.

Comment: depending on your app structure this could be easy or a major problem. Since you are using react then maybe you can have the csrf token retrieved in a promise and then shared with all components using a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Then each component can await for the token before sending any requests that need it, however if your setup allows it you might find an easier solution note that the same promise object is only resolved once

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for pointing out, let me try something like that.

Comment: Also take a look at the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook for when you're using functional components

Comment: @apokryfos I will edit question and will add current code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239781/discussion-between-manishkumar-adesara-and-apokryfos).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most basic use case:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const FetchContext = createContext();
const { Provider } = FetchContext;

const FetchProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [ publicAxios, setPublicAxios ] = useState(null)
    const [ authAxios, setAuthAxios ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCsrfToken = async () => {
          
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get('/api/csrf-token');
                setPublicAxios(axios.create({ baseURL: '/api', headers: { 
                   'X-CSRF-Token': data
                } });
                setAuthAxios(axios.create({ baseURL: '/api', headers: { 
                   'X-CSRF-Token': data
                } })

            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        };
        getCsrfToken();
    }, [ ]);

    return (
        <Provider value={{ authAxios, publicAxios }}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    );
};

export { FetchContext, FetchProvider }
```

and you can use it:

```
const UsersList = ({ children }) => {
    const { authAxios } = useContext(FetchContext);
    const [userList, setUserList] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
         async function getUsers() {
            try {
                const { data } = await authAxios.post(
                    '/users/list'
                );
                if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
                    setUserList(data)
                } else {
                    setUserList('No');
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
                setUserList('Error')
            }
        }
        if (authAxios !== null) {
            getUsers()
        }
    }, [authAxios]);
    
    return (
        <div>
            hello
        </div>
    )
```

Here `authAxios` will be null until the token is loaded and the instance is initialsed.

The important thing is to wrap all your components that need to use these instances in the context provider e.g.

```
<FetchProvider>
  <App />
</FetchProvider>
```

This will make the context available to all children of `<App />`

Comment: here in your example something is wrong, when getCsrfToken function is called, instead of setting new Axios instance it calls to endpoint  '/api'.
This is error
Promise {<rejected>: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vend…}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError